# How do we install PHP extensions for Phoronix Test Suite?

Tags: php, benchmarks

The [phoronix-test-suite](http://www.phoronix-test-suite.com/) package provides a good way to benchmark one's hardware. After installation using Software Centre on Ubuntu 13.10 Saucy Salamander, the package does not run properly. The following message appears:

> The following PHP extensions are REQUIRED by the Phoronix Test Suite:
>
> JSON PHP JSON support is required for OpenBenchmarking.org
>   communication.
>
> The following PHP extensions are OPTIONAL but recommended:
>
> PCNTL PHP PCNTL is highly recommended as it is required by some tests.
>   CURL PHP CURL is recommended for an enhanced download experience. PHP
>   FPDF PHP FPDF is recommended if wishing to generate PDF reports.

**How do we install the above extensions?**

According to the Phoronix website, the only requirements for the .deb file are:

php5-cli

Though this package is installed, the test suite will not run.

Comment: From [here](https://github.com/phoronix-test-suite/phoronix-test-suite/issues/334#issuecomment-455918260): _The `phoronix-test-suite` packages found in the Ubuntu archive are vastly outdated and unmaintained. You can install the [Phoronix Test Suite official Debian packages](http://phoronix-test-suite.com/?k=downloads) and will work fine with Ubuntu PHP5/PHP7._ Probably Ubuntu maintainers should remove `phoronix-test-suite` from official repos.

Answer (score 1):

Installing the package php5-json worked for me in Ubuntu 13.10:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-json
```